# Zodresolver unexpected array of NaN's

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hook-form, zod

I'm using a combination of  the LATEST versions of zod, react-hook-form, @hookform/resolvers and react-select.

Essentially, I have a schema that looks like this:

```
const selectOptions = z
  .array(
    z.object({
      value: z.union([z.string(), z.number()]),
      label: z.string()
    })
  )
  .transform((options) =>
    options.map(({ value }) => (!isNaN(Number(value)) ? Number(value) : value))
  );

const schema = z.object({
  foo: z.string(),
  options: z.union([selectOptions, something]).optional()
});
```

The `options` key is the one misbehaving specifically in my project. When selections are made using react-select, when submitting the form, I get an array of NaN's instead of the values of the selected options (`[NaN, NaN]`). The length of the NaN array matches the length of the selections.

The crazy thing is, this is happening in my project only. In my reproduction sandbox, I can't reproduce this problem.

Here's a link to my repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-zod-resolver-example-forked-rxvcd8?file=/src/App.js:484-834

My logic is *identical* to that repro, except that it has actual business logic. I have replicated exactly how I do it within the project (using the `omit`, validate on blur, etc.). In the `resolver` callback within `useForm`, the values are appropriate in my project - the transformer does its job and makes an array of numbers. It's only onSubmit when the array has the invalid values.

To clarify, in my project:

- [this line works and the result is, for example: [1, 2, 3, 4]](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-zod-resolver-example-forked-rxvcd8?file=/src/App.js:1126-1145)
- [this line doesn't work and ends up being [NaN, NaN, NaN]](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-zod-resolver-example-forked-rxvcd8?file=/src/App.js:1374-1448)

Why could I be getting a random array of NaN`s?